# Vector with unsigned int

Tags: c++11

My teacher assigned this question for me, where i have to create a code for fibonacci, i know how to make a fibonacci, but i can't really see what am i going to do with this code that he gave and said that it has to be on my code.

Can anyone make a code that satisfy this?
I'm really trying to understand, but i've tried googleing it, watching some yt tutorials, but couldnt understand what is this supose to do.

```
    #include "function.h"
    
    std::vector<unsigned int> fib_below_n( unsigned int n )
    {
        // ALL: add your code here
    
        // ALL: This is just a STUB. Change the RETURN for what you judge right.
        return std::vector<unsigned int>{};
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some more details to get you started:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> retval;
unsigned prev= 1;
unsigned current = 1;
// loop to generate fibonacci numbers
while (current < n) {
   retval.push_back (current);             /// <<<<< here
   // >> generate the next number
   }
return retval;
```